# Persist variables (and maybe input history) across restarts

Tags: hooks, start-up, persistence, savehist-mode

Sometimes I wish to persist the value of some variable when I quit emacs. For example, I would like to do this for `compile-command`.

Now, I guess I could find the hook that is run when Emacs quits (assuming there is one, a quick scan through the list of hooks did not turn up an obvious candidate) and save that variable to a file of my own; and reload it in `init.el`. But surely someone else had the same need already. Is there a package or even some inbuilt way to achieve this?

Bonus question: it would be *awesome* to also be able to save the history of the same. I.e., when I type `M-x compile`, I can scroll back through the previous compile commands. Would be great to keep that. Same for `M-!` with shell commands and so on.

Comment: It sounds like file-local or directory-local variables might serve in the specific use case described here.

Comment: @JohnKitchin yes, especialy directory-local would serve for my `compile` related stuff; thanks for bringing that up. I'll use those if no good answers turn up.

Comment: Yes, @drew, that seems like a direct duplicate. Didn't use the correct search terms, looks like.

Comment: Please delete the question, in that case.  Thx.

Comment: Well, since I was not finding that other question, I'll keep this on. The other one is specific to two use cases; this one is generic for all kinds of variables. Yes, the answers are similar or the same, but since I at least did not find the other, this one might be practical for other people searching for "my" search terms... @Drew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there ... some inbuilt way to achieve this?

Yes -- if you enable `savehist-mode` in your init file, then any variable you add to `savehist-additional-variables` will automatically be saved and restored between sessions.

> Bonus question: it would be awesome to also be able to save the history of the same

`savehist-mode` automatically saves most history variables, but this one is a bit different, so you'll need to treat it the same way.

Try this:

```el
(savehist-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'compile-command)
(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'compile-history)
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly as ordered! ;) I also added `compilation-directory` and `shell-command-history`.